# How to redeem Apple tv+ 1 year subscription when you purchase a new Mac?

Tags: apple-id, appletv

I just bought new MacBook  Pro 2019, I already installed all updates but I cant get a promised 1-year subscription (tried both app and tv.apple.com).

What precise step by step process is used to redeem this benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few day and multiple restarts subscription button showed in an Apple TV app, it looks like it is only matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from Apple's official promotional document.

> **Redeem your 1 year free in the Apple TV app starting November 1, 2019**. Make
>   sure your eligible device is running the latest iOS, iPadOS, tvOS, or macOS.
>
> > **Offer must be claimed in the Apple TV app within 3 months** after first setting
> >     up your new device. To see the offer appear, you will need to sign in with your
> >     Apple ID on your new device. If you’ve purchased your new device before the
> >     launch of Apple TV+ on November 1, you will have 3 months starting November
> >     1 to redeem

Comment: I've edited this to be more about documenting the step by step. If you want to edit this - that's awesome. No need to, but it might help